# python replit database throwing typeError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to make functions to save, get, and get all for the Replit Python database. It doesn't work and I can't find out why.

Get all function:

```
def loadAll(user):
    if user in db.keys():
        return db[user]
    if user not in db.keys():
        db[user] = {}
        return db[user]
```

It throws an error at `return db[user]`.

This is the code that fires the function (I'm using the discord.py commands extension.):

```
@bot.command(name = "getMyData")
async def getUserData(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author)
    await ctx.send(loadAll(ctx.author))
```

The error message says:
`TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes`

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure you don't have to use `db.keys()`, just `if user in db`...

Comment: In any case, **please post a [mcve]**. If you are getting an error, post the *full error message* including the stack trace

Comment: You seem to be duplicating the function of `defaultdict`.

Comment: @Barmar sure, but this is for a database object that uses the `dict` interface, so you can't just replace it with a `defaultdict`.

Comment: In that case, it's duplicating `return db.setdefault(user, {})`

Comment: Which `return db[user]` is the error happening at? Although I don't see how it could fail in either place. One is after checking if the key exists, the other is after adding the key.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried using db instead of db.keys(), but it throws an error if I use just db.

Comment: @hydro *what error*? Again, you really must be more specific.

Comment: @Barmar The error happens at the last line of the function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It says TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Comment: @hydro **post the full error message including the stack trace in the question itself**. Please take the time to read [ask] and the [help] for information on what is expected for a question seeking debugging help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the database key to not just be the user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replit Database doesn't support integers as keys. Stringify the key beforehand.